duplicates- take the second value as ouput and reference against the first
I am stuck to find a good function to solve my problem.



ptf
ISIN
CUSTOM CODE




FA_ABC
AAPL 06/20/25 P155 EQUITY
583417_FA_ABC_U03_EUR


FA_ABC
CA21037X1006
583417_FA_ABC_U03_EUR


FA_ABC
CA21037X1345
583417_FA_ABC_U03_EUR


LV_XYZ
AAPL 06/20/25 P155 EQUITY
7259157_LV_XYZ_013_USD


LV_XYZ
CA21037X1006
190167_LV_XYZ_S01_CAD


LV_XYZ
CA21037X1345
572720_LV_XYZ_W02_CAD



I want to assign new codes for securities in this table, for duplicated items duplicated exactly twice, by assigning new codes to items with ptf code FA_ABC with custom code from items with ptf code LV_XYZ  for the same ISIN.
Here's the desired outcome - from and to codes are show in in bold italics:



ptf
ISIN
CUSTOM CODE
DESIRED CUSTOM CODE




FA_ABC
AAPL 06/20/25 P155 EQUITY
583417_FA_ABC_U03_EUR
7259157_LV_XYZ_013_USD


FA_ABC
CA21037X1006
583417_FA_ABC_U03_EUR
190167_LV_XYZ_S01_CAD


FA_ABC
CA21037X1345
583417_FA_ABC_U03_EUR
572720_LV_XYZ_W02_CAD


LV_XYZ
AAPL 06/20/25 P155 EQUITY
7259157_LV_XYZ_013_USD
7259157_LV_XYZ_013_USD


LV_XYZ
CA21037X1006
190167_LV_XYZ_S01_CAD
190167_LV_XYZ_S01_CAD


LV_XYZ
CA21037X1345
572720_LV_XYZ_W02_CAD
572720_LV_XYZ_W02_CAD



I have tried a lot with if, countif, match and vlookup but still don't get what I want
[what I see now vs. what I would like to see][1]
It seems I am not able to embed images, only links to it
Any help or hint is really appreciated
thank you.

Can you post your attempts ([edit] them in), maybe you were close and we can direct you on the right track. Also post your initial data and the desired result, preferably in text/Markdown table.

I'm not quite following your question and your images didn't clarify the question. Duplicates in every column, and you need to have you custom code duplicated again for a different set of rows but I'm not following the logic anywhere here and not really seeing the pattern either. Please try to explain this a bit more clearly. Also you seem to have the same image twice in your question.

Unclear what logic you need: maybe this? =CHOOSE(COUNTIF($A$1:@$A:$A,@$A:$A),"7259157_LV_XYZ_O13_USD","190167_LV_XYZ_S01_CAD","572720_LV_XYZ_W02_CAD")

thank you but I always get the last code 572720_LV_XYZ_W02_CAD. Apologies for not being clear at all. I am a noob here. what I would like to see are the three codes, attached to the ISINs of LV_XYZ, be attached also to the ISINs of FA_ABC.

Ok, but what "code" do you currently use to get your values?

Is this what you're trying to get - enter the following in D2 (clear cells below):
Requires Microsoft 365
=LET(
    data, TRIM(A2:XLOOKUP(TRUE, C:C <> "", C:C, , , -1)),
    to, "LV_XYZ",
    from, "FA_ABC",
    ptf, INDEX(data, , 1),
    ISIN, INDEX(data, , 2),
    custom, INDEX(data, , 3),
    new_custom, FILTER(HSTACK(ISIN, custom), ptf = to),
    IF(
        ptf = from,
        XLOOKUP(
            ISIN,
            INDEX(new_custom, , 1),
            INDEX(new_custom, , 2)
        ),
        custom
    )
)


Data used:



ptf
ISIN
CUSTOM CODE




FA_ABC
AAPL 06/20/25 P155 EQUITY
583417_FA_ABC_U03_EUR


FA_ABC
CA21037X1006
583417_FA_ABC_U03_EUR


FA_ABC
CA21037X1345
583417_FA_ABC_U03_EUR


LV_XYZ
AAPL 06/20/25 P155 EQUITY
7259157_LV_XYZ_013_USD


LV_XYZ
CA21037X1006
190167_LV_XYZ_S01_CAD


LV_XYZ
CA21037X1345
572720_LV_XYZ_W02_CAD




thank you but I got a SPILL error, I am using Microsoft 365

Please clear the cells below where you entered the formula. Formula will spill the results

thank you! it works! awesome! I need now to apply this only to duplicates securities = 2.. in the original file, I have also other codes duplicated  more than 2.. will try to find out how to nest LET with other functions.. I am thinking to use IF(COUNTIF..) , let's see what I can find out thank you again
